# JVM doen't exit in Spring Integrations

Tags: spring-integration

I'm new to spring integration and I'm using the following code,

public class Main {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "trail03ApplicationContext.xml");
    MessageChannel channel = applicationContext.getBean(
            "helloMessageChannel", MessageChannel.class);
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("World").build();
    channel.send(message);


}
```

}

I don't have any problems in the code but the jvm doesn't exit after sending the message. It still runs in the background. It was evident from the jvmvisual viewer. Is there are anything that needs to shut down. I'm using eclipse for testing the applications.

This is my application Context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<channel id="helloMessageChannel">

</channel>


<gateway service-interface="trail03.api.MessageService" id="myGateway" default-request-channel="helloMessageChannel"/>

<service-activator input-channel="helloMessageChannel"
    ref="helloMessageService" method="sayHello" />


<beans:bean id="helloMessageService" class="trail03.impl.MessageServiceImpl" />
```

Comment: post the log file and your spring context. the statement "the jvm doesn't exit" doesn't make much sense

Comment: This is my application Context

Comment: What does `helloMessageService` do? If it holds onto the thread, the JVM won't exit. Run `jstack <pid>` to take a thread dump to see what threads are holding up the JVM exit.